# Best practice for deleting multipe rows across tables in db

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering what is best practice when deleting multiple rows and items from a database. I'm working in C# and trying to make the process of deleting items faster so want to move this action to a stored procedure rather than calling the database for each item.

My setup is similar to a file system, so I have Folders, SubFolders and Files. Files can be of different types (e.g. XML, TXT, PDF) and certain File types have other attributes stored in different tables connected with the Id of the file. Files are connected to Folders and SubFolders in specific File_To_Folder and File_To_SubFolder tables.

Now, I want to create a script for deleting a Folder which has to delete from all of these different tables as well. Currently I have in place stored procedures for deleting a single File which deletes all items connected to it. My question is, what are the advantages/disadvantages to

**a)** using a cursor to loop through all items in the folder and call sp_deletePDF/sp_deleteTXT for each item.

or

**b)** creating a custom script figuring out all rows that need to be deleted from each table on it's own and just use one line `delete from {table} where id in (id1, id2, id3)`?

Comment: Why not use foreign key constraints? (Although perhaps the reference goes on the wrong way for that to work)

Comment: You mean something like delete cascade? It wouldn't work for everything, not all rows are connected with a foreign key because of legacy issues